# Event handler for sharepoint list link

Tags: sharepoint

I want to add a link on a column of a list (one link for each row).  When user clicks on a link, I want start some task.  What event can I use to handle this and how can I get the row index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use event receiver instead you can use calculated column with formula which generates item specific URL e.g.

```
=CONCATENATE("<DIV><a href='","http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.",Title,"'>",Title,"</a></DIV>")
```

[Here](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/how-to-open-hyperlinks-in-a-new-window-or-not/) you can find more info about this approach. If you need more info feel free to ask.

Comment: This sounds interesting.  At the present time, I don't have much luck with event receiver any way.  So I will try this too.  Thanks

Comment: I was able to do this:  http://localhost:32903/Default.aspx?SharepointListName=Bach_test&amp;SharepointRowId=190

Comment: But what I want to do is:  <a href='http://localhost:32903/Default.aspx?SharepointListName=Bach_test&amp;SharepointRowId=190' target='_blank'>Edit Form</a>

Comment: I tried your way, but could not get it to work.  Maybe I did not do it right?

Comment: Describe your problem I'll try to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You could create column with HyperLink type and programmatically populate the column in event receiver (in `ItemAdded` / `ItemUpdated` events). The URL would link to your HTTP handler that would perform the action on item by its ID (passed in the URL).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Not sure I understand everything but definitely try this out very shortly